# Trouble generating random -1 through +1 in Java

Tags: java, random

I'm trying to figure out how to best generate a random number between -1 and 1. I thought this was the formula below but my output is always 0s and 1s, no negatives.

```
random.nextInt(max + 1 - min) + min
```

Here's the actual code:

```
int xRand = random.nextInt((1 + 1 + 1) - 1);
int yRand = random.nextInt((1 + 1 + 1) - 1);

System.out.println("x: " + xRand);
System.out.println("y: " + yRand);
```

Comment: "`random.nextInt(max + 1 - min) + min`" Note that isn't what you've got in the code. (Perhaps it would be clearer if you created variables `min` and `max`)

Comment: Your formula is correct, but you're not applying it at all. max is 1, min is -1, so it should be `random.nextInt(1 + 1 - (-1)) + (-1)`, or `random.nextInt(3) - 1`. You're using `random.nextInt(2)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate random integers within a specific range in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/363681/608639), [How to generate random positive and negative numbers in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/363681/608639), etc. More generally, [java generate random number in range site:stackoverflow.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+generate+random+number+in+range+site%3Astackoverflow.com)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`random.nextInt(1 + 1 + 1) - 1`

`random.nextInt(1 + 1 + 1)` will generate a random integer from 0 to 2 (think of mod 3)

Adding `-1` will then result in it generating from -1 to 1

Answer (score 2):

You state in the question

```
random.nextInt(max + 1 - min) + min
```

But, using `max == 1` and `min == -1`, you have written

```
random.nextInt((max + 1 - min) + min)
```

Move the final `-1` out of the brackets.

```
int xRand = random.nextInt(1 + 1 + 1) - 1;
```

(And consider using variables named `min` and `max` instead of magic numbers that you won't know the meaning of when you come back to this code later).

Comment: ahh of course! the brackets fooled me bad. thank you much!